# A coil of inductance 0.50 H and resistance 100Ω is connected to a 240 V, 50 Hz ac supply. What exactly is 240V here?

Tags: current, resistors, ac, inductor, homework

As far as I've understood, doesn't 240V represent V<sub>m</sub> here? We solved questions in class like these (but in those it was inductance only) and there we took V<sub>m</sub> one as the one given with the frequency. 
But when I was browsing the web, it another website showed V<sub>m</sub> as √2*240 ??

Which one am I getting confused in? What is the correct one?

Comment: From context, 240v is the RMS voltage, not peak.  Mains AC voltages are virtually always RMS unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Define your terms, particularly since you say "here" as if you're referring to something, but then never give us its context.  If I were reanimating corpses, $V_M$ might mean the voltage applied to the monster.  I _assume_, but cannot _know_ that your $V_M$ means the mains voltage.  A schematic would help.

Comment: @TimWescott here as in in the question given in the main title. Vm = V peak

Comment: @user1850479 alrightt and what about current? should we take it as RMS value unless mentioned otherwise. in most questions, it's given this way: coil has resistance x ohm and takes a current 1.5A across 250V, 60Hz supply. here 1.5A = I_rms ?

Comment: You can assume voltage and current are in comparable units. However, in your example it actually does not matter as you do not need to what units are used since you aren't calculating power.

Comment: @user1850479 alright. if we had to calculate power how would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to have rules and, some rules tell us what numbers mean in the absence of overriding information. So, if all we know is a voltage value, then the default assumption is either DC voltage or RMS AC voltage.

So, in cases where only a voltage value is stated and, there is no other context, we cannot be sure whether the number represents alternating or direct quantities. But that doesn't matter because, the heat produced by (say) 100 volts DC when applied to a fixed value resistor, is the same heat produced by the same resistor when fed with 100 volts AC RMS.